# Exchange.GROUPED_EXCHANGE not available after aggregation in Apache Camel 3.7.2

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, camel-cxf

After upgrading from Apache Camel **2.x** to **3.7.2** in our Java 11 project we experience some crudities in a route configuration class, extending the `RouteBuilder` [(Documentation)](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/route-builder.html) class. With Camel 2 I used the SimpleExpression `${property[" + Exchange.GROUPED_EXCHANGE + "]}`, which has now been renamed in Camel 3.x to `exchangeProperty` [(Migration Guide)](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_languages). So far, so good.

```java
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    final SimpleExpression documentAppendix =
        new SimpleExpression("${body.appendix}");

    final SimpleExpression groupedExchanges =
        new SimpleExpression("${exchangeProperty[" + Exchange.GROUPED_EXCHANGE + "]}");

    from("direct://input")
        .choice()
            .when(documentAppendix)
                .split(documentAppendix, new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
                .to("direct://input.splitted")
                .end()
                .setBody(groupedExchanges)
                .endChoice()
            .otherwise()
                .setBody(constant(Lists.newArrayList()))
        .end();
    
    // ... omitted
    
}
```

After running the tests, everything failed because the body did not contain the expected number of appendices. At first, we thought there might be a problem with `exchangeProperty` but after some time spent with the debugger we've found out the following trail where the property gets "lost":

```
         GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy
                         |
                         v
           AbstractListAggregationStrategy
(This class sets the "CamelGroupedExchange" property!)
                         |
                         v
                 AggregateProcessor
                 doAggregation(...)
       ExchangeHelper.preparteAggregation(...)
```

The expected return after aggregation should be a list of objects, accessible via the `CamelGroupedExchange` or `${exchangeProperty[" + Exchange.GROUPED_EXCHANGE + "]}` but it gets overridden with the `newExchange` in `ExchangeHelper.preparteAggregation`.

As we did not find more evidence, could someone explain this weird behaviour after upgrading Camel to 3.7.2? Maybe there have been breaking changes in ExchangeHelper and the available ExchangePattern/MEP Pattern [(CAMEL-13286)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13286) but we were not able to break down the issue.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We figured out that the `AbstractListAggregationStrategy` in Camel 3.7.2 now sets the property as `In` body on completion:

```java
public abstract class AbstractListAggregationStrategy<V> implements AggregationStrategy {
    public AbstractListAggregationStrategy() {
    }

    public abstract V getValue(Exchange exchange);

    public boolean isStoreAsBodyOnCompletion() {
        return true;
    }

    public void onCompletion(Exchange exchange) {
        if (exchange != null && this.isStoreAsBodyOnCompletion()) {
            List<V> list = (List)exchange.removeProperty("CamelGroupedExchange");
            if (list != null) {
                exchange.getIn().setBody(list);
            }
        }

    }

    // omitted

}
```

With this change our `.setBody(groupedExchanges)` is redundant and we are able to access the list of exchanges via `getIn()`.